# How can I implement a user-written lazy constraint callback in concert CPLEX with C++?

Tags: cplex, c++, callback

I am trying to implement a user-written lazy constraint callback in concert CPLEX with C++. Although I know there exists a way to implement callbacks in concert CPLEX with C++ via [macros](http://www-eio.upc.edu/lceio/manuals/cplex-11/html/usrcplex/callbacks16.html#1009168), I am looking for a way to implement lazy constraint callback without macros.

At this moment I know that I must create a class that inherits from the class `IloCplex.LazyConstraintCallback` (the documentation of this class can be found [here](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/%7Ediam/ro/online/cplex/cplex1271/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplex.LazyConstraintCallback.html)). I am aware that this type of implementation requires (a kind of) profound understanding of the algorithms used by CPLEX, however, I want to learn how to do it without the using of macros. After spending some days looking for any code in C++ I could not find anything. Therefore, I am here to know if anyone has any template of how it could be done.

Comment: Would you see [CPLEX optimization forum](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum%3Fid%3D11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000002059&ved=2ahUKEwiG0OeQkc_mAhUP8xQKHWjOCz8QFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw0tIYAyD052HYslAG_Z5Pci)?

Comment: I could not find any topic related to the user-written callback in CPLEX with C++, I could find topics related to python, however, is not the same thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have it almost all right, with a few caveats. Let's say I want to implement a Foo Lazy Constraint:

```
#include <ilocplex/ilocplex.h>
#include <ilocplex/ilocplexi.h>

struct Foo : IloCplex::LazyConstraintCallbackI {
  // Your code goes here...
};
```

There are three main things you need to put inside your class; two of these are documented (more or less) and one comes from my experience:

1. A reference to the current CPLEX environment and any variable you might want to use, captured via the constructor. Pass the environment up to the parent constructor. This is the part that comes from my experience... indeed, you might think that to access the CPLEX environment object you can just use the inherited `getEnv()` method, but for me this consistently causes crashes if I do something like `IloExpr lhs{getEnv()};`. Perhaps some more knowledgeable user can explain why.

```
#include <ilocplex/ilocplex.h>
#include <ilocplex/ilocplexi.h>

struct Foo : IloCplex::LazyConstraintCallbackI {
  IloEnv& env;
  IloNumVar& x;
  
  Foo(IloEnv& env, IloNumVar& x) :
    LazyConstraintCallbackI{env}, env{env}, x{x} {}
};
```

2. Implement a `duplicateCallback()` method for CPLEX to use internally. This always looks the same, I basically just copy-paste it from project to project.

```
#include <ilocplex/ilocplex.h>
#include <ilocplex/ilocplexi.h>

struct Foo : IloCplex::LazyConstraintCallbackI {
  IloEnv& env;
  IloNumVar& x;
  
  Foo(IloEnv& env, IloNumVar& x) :
    LazyConstraintCallbackI{env}, env{env}, x{x} {}

  [[nodiscard]] IloCplex::CallbackI* duplicateCallback() const override {
    return new(env) Foo{*this};
  }
};
```

3. Implement a `main()` function that adds the cut using the parent's `add()` method. This is the juicy part... here you access the current solution, decide whether you need a new cut and, in this case, add it.

```
#include <ilocplex/ilocplex.h>
#include <ilocplex/ilocplexi.h>

struct Foo : IloCplex::LazyConstraintCallbackI {
  IloEnv& env;
  IloNumVar& x;
  
  Foo(IloEnv& env, IloNumVar& x) :
    LazyConstraintCallbackI{env}, env{env}, x{x} {}

  [[nodiscard]] IloCplex::CallbackI* duplicateCallback() const override {
    return new(env) Foo{*this};
  }

  void main() override {
    const auto x_value = getValue(x);
    
    if(x_value < 2.0) {
      try {
        add(x >= 2.0);
      } catch(IloException& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception while adding lazy constraint for x = " << x_value << ": " << e.getMessage() << "\n";
        throw;
    }
  }
};
```

Note how I can use the inherited `getValue()` to access variables' values, and finally `add()` to eventually add a cut. If `add()` is called at least once, CPLEX knows that it needs to re-solve the node; otherwise, it assumes that no cuts are needed and proceeds with branching. If the lazy constraint should not join the "global" pool of constraints, but should only be active in the subtree of the current node, use `addLocal()` instead of `add()`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any C++ code using a lazy constraint callback, although I could show you a Java example if you can't find anything better. The basic approach, IIRC, is to create an instance of class `IloCplex::LazyConstraintCallbackI`. In it, you implement the `main()` method, which is what CPLEX will call to invoke the callback. Inside the `main` method, you call various `get` methods to get the proposed solution, do whatever calculations you need to do, and call `add()` or `addLocal()` once for each cut you want to add. If you exit `main()` without adding any cuts, you are accepting the proposed solution.

Comment: Oh, Nice! It would be very interesting, could you send to me this class and the code passages used for initializing the class and for using the object in the model?

Comment: Since you added the comment, I see that Alberto Santini added sample C++ code. If you still need the Java code, let me know, but Alberto's code is C++, which will spare you some non-obvious conversion steps.